# Python asyncio queue doesnt finish

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have one producer and 3 consumers. Each consumer waits to acquire a global lock before it can proceed. The program runs and doesnt finish and come out of the while loop. Could you tell me where it is going wrong?

```
import asyncio
import random

async def produce(queue, n):
    for x in range(1, n + 1):
        # produce an item
        print('producing {}/{}'.format(x, n))
        # simulate i/o operation using sleep
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
        item = str(x)
        # put the item in the queue
        await queue.put(item)

    # indicate the producer is done
    await queue.put(None)


async def consume(queue, lock):
    while True:
        item = await queue.get()
        if item is None:
            # the producer emits None to indicate that it is done
            break
        # wait for an item from the producer
        async with lock:
            # process the item
            print('consuming item {}...'.format(item))
            # simulate i/o operation using sleep
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
lock = asyncio.Lock()
queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
producer_coro = produce(queue, 10)
consumers = []
for _ in range(3):
    consumers.append(consume(queue, lock))
all_coroutines = []
all_coroutines.append(producer_coro)
all_coroutines.extend(consumers)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(all_coroutines))
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the consumer:

```
        if item is None:
            # the producer emits None to indicate that it is done
            break
```

The `None` sentinel is only picked up by a single consumer, and the rest are left waiting for the next value to arrive through the queue. A simple fix is to return the sentinel value back to the queue:

```
        if item is None:
            # The producer emits None to indicate that it is done.
            # Propagate it to other consumers and quit.
            await queue.put(None)
            break
```

Alternatively, `produce` could enqueue as many `None` sentinels as there are consumers - but that would require the producer to know how many consumers there are, which is not always desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer @user4815162342 provided, try:

```
if item is None and queue.qsize() == 0:
    await queue.put(None)
    break
```

I had an issue where the consumer also had to `queue.put()` to the same queue to rerun the function but it hung at the end without the both conditions.